# Is there any phpunit/selenium documentation?

Tags: testing, selenium, phpunit

I've searched and searched - but I can't find any. There are lots of pages that claim to be documentation, but most of them are just lists of methods with no arguments or usage info, or are simply how to guides that don't cover the whole library.

Does anyone have a link to that full documentation?

I'm having to guess at what syntax to use for commands, as half of them are just "pass through" commands that aren't even implemented in the PHP.

For example - how do I use assertSelectOptions()?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Honestly, the only complete documentation available that is semi-useful (only semi-useful because it hasn't been updated since 09) I've been able to find is this:

http://release.seleniumhq.org/selenium-core/1.0/reference.html

Comment: Thanks - I guess that's the nearest I'm going to get! I'll leave this question open a while longer - just in case.

Answer (score 1):

I agree that there isn't a clear documentation set for the "new" Selenium 2 version, which is frustrating.

Leet is right - that's the best documentation I've found too, but it's not PHP-specific and so sometimes vague on return types, error handling etc. There is actually a minor version update here:
http://release.seleniumhq.org/selenium-core/1.0.1/reference.html

It seems the last time the main site included documentation on the actual methods was around v3.3 http://phpunit.de/manual/3.3/en/selenium.html. If you change the version number you can see the list of methods getting shorter! You may find some older info here.

Also there are recent discussions in the Github issues around the new @method syntax and compatiblity with documentors and IDE code-assist, so perhaps they are busy working on the new documentation?
https://github.com/sebastianbergmann/phpunit-selenium/issues/251

I have just tried to build the documentation from the source with phpDocumentor2, and indeed there are a lot of errors regarding the new @method syntax and resulting doc set is pretty slim on information! I guess this is a side-effect of the methods being accessed via __call, and not real methods, making it all a bit obscure.

Update: I wrote this article after exensive research into the the documentation for v1 and v2.

http://scipilot.org/blog/2013/06/30/re-learning-unit-testing-selenium-2-phpunit-selenium/

Comment: BTW as mention in other questions, there are some Net Tuts which have good info, but obviously not a reference. However if you're lucky the'll cover what you're after!http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/how-to-use-selenium-2-with-phpunit/